# What is function with brackets mean?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know what is `test[name]` mean?

```
function test(value){
  copy(value||{},this);
}
test[name] = function(){
    return "test"
}
```

Comment: `test[name]` is an array element which in this case is assigned a function.

Comment: @milkshake array element? what?

Comment: @Esailija an item in an array, it also looks like its key will be decided by a variable.

Comment: I don't see any array, I see a method assignment to a function object

Comment: @Esailija a method with an index? I suppose it could be an object also.

Comment: @milkshake Just about everything in JavaScript is an object, including arrays. That doesn't mean that every object is an array (and the object in the question is not one).

Comment: @Juhana, Esailija thanks for the lesson :D

Comment: Reading your code example FIRST I would have bet that you ask what "copy(value||{},this);" means!

Answer (score 6):

This will be easiest to explain with an example:

```
var name = "foo";
test[name] = function(){
    return "test"
};
```

This would add a property named "foo" to the object `test`, and the value of that property is a function. It doesn't matter in this case that the object `test` is actually a function, you can assign properties to functions just like any other object in JavaScript.

You could call this function using any of the following methods:

- `test[name]()`
- `test["foo"]()`
- `test.foo()`

Note that `test[name]()` will not work if the `name` variable is assigned to something different, for example `name = 'bar'`.

Comment: since the name is a property of test, but when I use console.log(test), it only display the function. should it be an object?

Comment: Functions are objects, but they way they are represented in `console.log()` depends on how `toString()` is implemented for functions.  To print the function as an object you can use `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.apply(test))`. **edit:** This actually depends on the browser, it looks like Chrome and Firefox do not use `toString()` for `console.log()` on objects, not really sure how to get a function logged like an object for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has two sets of notation for accessing objects, dot notation (obj.property) and bracket notation (object[property]). More on that at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators).

`test[name] = function (){}` assigns an anonymous function to the `name` property on the the `test` object (which itself is a function). In this case (as noted by the comments) the variable `name` is being used to access the property.

This may seem a little strange at first, but it's helpful to remember that in javascript, functions are objects.

Comment: `name` isn't a string.

Comment: `name` is a variable, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

All functions in Javascript are also objects. This adds a property to the `test` function object with a value which is an anonymous function.

For example:

```
function test(){
  return "foo";
}

// test is a function, so it is also an object and 
// it can have properties assigned to it
test.x = function(){
   return "bar";
};

test();   // "foo"
test.x(); // "bar"
```

Of course just like with any object you can also use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
var name = 'hello';
test[name] = function(){
  return "HELLO!";
};

test.hello(); // "HELLO!"
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, [functions are objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).  They have properties.  `test[name]` sets a property (named whatever the `name` variable holds) to a function.

Answer (score 0):

when you have a javascript object with defined properties you can access the property either with the dot notation `obj.property` or with the square brackets notation `obj[property]`
the property could also be a function so if you have an object:

`var test = {
  foo : function(arg){ console.log(arg) },
  bar : 'hello'
};`

you can call `test.foo('bar')` also by doing `test['foo']('bar')`
This is especially useful in iterations or when you dont know a priori what the name of the property is going to be. For example:

```
var fun = 'foo';
test[fun]('hello world');
```

Naturally it's up to you to do proper checks such as

`if ('function'==typeof test['foo']){ test['foo']('bar'); }`

Also note that you can do checks on the fly like so:

`test[ fun || 'foo']('hello');`

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

> One can think of an object as an associative array (a.k.a. map, dictionary, hash, lookup table). The keys in this array are the names of object members
>
> There are two ways to access object members: dot notation and bracket notation (a.k.a. subscript operator).

So

```
test[name] = function (
```

means: there are (if everything is ok) two objects: `test` and `name` (and we know that at least `test` is present, because you defined it one line before: `function test(value)`)

take the `test` object (if there isn't a test `object` an error will happen). Then access the key/value pair with the key calculated from the `name` object and there put a function.

Now, how the key is calculated from the `name` object? The same page from before tells us:

> Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method.

Note that the description is a little wrong... `test[null] == test["null"]` and `test[undefined] == test["undefined"]`, so perhaps the truth is that under the covers something like `String(key).valueOf()` is done (the `String` function will convert `null` to `"null"` and `undefined` to `"undefined"`)

Some examples (where => means "is equivalent to, with this values")

```
var name = 'foo';
test[name] => test['foo']

var name = 123;
test[name] => test['123']

var name = 123.3;
test[name] => test['123.3']

var name = new Date();
test[name] => test['Wed Aug 14 2013 17:35:35 GMT+0200 (...)']

var name = null;
test[name] => test['null']

var name = undefined;
test[name] => test['undefined']

var name = [];
test[name] => test['']

var name = [1,2,3];
test[name] => test['1,2,3']

var name = {};
test[name] => test['object Object']
```

and so on...

Answer (score -1):

The brackets are how you reference a property via a key into the hash that javascript objects are.

Comment: I suppose this is technically correct, but I doubt it will clarify the matter for OP at all.